# How to add custom option during add to cart in Magento 2.2?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2, custom-options, addtocart, unserialize

I want to add the custom option when click on **add to cart button** in Magento 2.2

I am using the code in Observer:

```
<?php    
namespace Vendor\Delivery\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
Json $serializer = null,
RequestInterface $request
) {
$this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
$this->_request = $request;
}

public function execute(EventObserver $observer) {
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$additionalOptions = [];

        if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')){
          $additionalOptions = (array) unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
        }

       // $post = $this->_request->getParam('print_style'); // Your data added here
    $post = array('Print Style' => 'Test');

        if (is_array($post)) {
            foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == '' || $value == '') {
                    continue;
                }

                $additionalOptions[] = array(
                    'label' => $key,
                    'value' => $value
                );
            }
        }


  if(count($additionalOptions) > 0){
            $item->addOption(array(
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));
        }

    }

}
```

**I have changed the line for Magento 2.2**

```
'value' => $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)
```

**For magento 2.1 its working below**

```
 'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
```

I am getting this Error in console:

```
{"message":"Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in \/home\/root\/M2\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Helper\/Product\/Configuration.php on line 118"}
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: does this `print_style` option you are trying to add comes from an input in the product page that is submited along with the product form?

Comment: No, I have added the manual post in an array format for the test.
$post = array('Print Style' => 'Test');

Comment: Have you got any solution? if pls share